# How to open my App for update in App Store without having it released

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, updates

I'm coding an IPhone/IPad App and have a webservice to check if the version is too old.

If the version is too old, then a message should appear a say: "Version too old. Click on the button to download the newest version in the app store."

The user should now be linked to the app in the app store.

How can I get the full link without having my app released in the app store and have an ID?

Best regards
Tino

Comment: what do you mean with "get the full link without having my app released in the app store?"
If you want to redirect the user to your app in the app store, that app must be there...

Comment: you can get prerelease ID and check the update is available or not

Answer (score 0):

One option is to send your app for a testFlight test. It allows you to have the full App Store link without releasing the app to the public.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `http://appstore.com/<companyname>/<appname>` as per [this guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1633/_index.html).

This will, however, probably redirect via Safari first (I have not tried). But you can use this for the first version and later change it to the real URL in an update.